# How to set the default screen style environment to elegant code?

Tags: formatting, customization, default

I want to set the default screen style environment to elegant code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To set the default, open the Option Inspector with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+O. You can also do Alt+E to open the edit menu, then P to open the Preferences GUI. Then go to Advanced Settings and where it says "For all other option settings: Open Option Inspector."
[image]
[image]

Next, search for ScreenStyleEnvironment. Next, select Show option values Global Preferences.
[image]
You should see this:
[image]
The options marked with a black x on the left are different from the default. The default for [ScreenStyleEnvironment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScreenStyleEnvironment.html) is "Working". Enter "Elegant" to change it to Elegant. This is part of Wolfram Research's Elegant Code Project, starting in Version 13.3 of the Wolfram Language.
For more details, see the section in Stephen Wolfram's blog post announcing the release of 13.3 titled ["The Elegant Code Project"](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/llm-tech-and-a-lot-more-version-13-3-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica#the-elegant-code-project).
I'm not sure if there's a way to do this programmatically. I think the only way to do this is with the Option Inspector GUI.

I did discover a problem with this. When editing a ResourceFunction, the tools like Template Input go away so you have to switch back to the ScreenStyleEnvironment Working to get the toolbar back.

Richard Hennigan has created a ResourceFunction to add this to any notebook, not just a Function Repository notebook named [AddDocumentationTools](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddDocumentationTools/).

[image]
The toolbar is back:
[image]
Feel free to comment on ways to programmatically change this setting and how to resolve the issue with the Function Repository toolbar.

To resolve the issue, use the function AddDocumentationTools:
[image]
The problem is the Submit to Repository is gone so I have to change the setting to submit the function, then I can change it back to Elegant code.

Actually, don't use AddDocumentationTools as a workaround for this. Here's why.
This is a new ResourceFunction notebook with the environment Elegant.
[image]

I haven't used AddDocumentationTools.

To store the input notebook as a notebook object that can be manipulated from the kernel as a symbolic notebook option, run `nb = InputNotebook[]`. You can also use [SelectedNotebook](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectedNotebook.html) or [EvaluationNotebook](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationNotebook.html) as an alternative to [InputNotebook](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputNotebook.html). This should return the notebook object for the current notebook. Then to see the current options for ScreenStyleEnvironment, evaluate `Options[nb, ScreenStyleEnvironment]`, which in my case returns `{ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Elegant"}`

Here is what I see:

[image]

To change the environment to working, use

```mathematica
SetOptions[nb, ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

I now see the Submit to Repository button:
[image]

However, if I switch back to the Elegant environment with

```mathematica
SetOptions[nb, ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Elegant"]
```

[image: Elegant ScreenStyleEnvironment]
then use AddDocumentationTools

```mathematica
ResourceFunction["AddDocumentationTools"][]
```

[image: AddDocumentationTools picture with Elegant code ScreenStyleEnvironment]
then change back to ScreenStyleEnvironment Working, the Submit to Repository button will be gone:
[image]
I think this is because of this: "By default, ResourceFunction["AddDocumentationTools"] will alter the style definitions of the notebook in order to properly display some formatted elements." (source:[Details for the ResourceFunction AddDocumentationTools](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddDocumentationTools/)). There is an option you can use. "To preserve style definitions, use the option "SetStyleDefinitions"→False.". This could be used as a workaround, but this leads to other issues. As Richard Hennigan notes in the Options section for AddDocumentationTools's documentation page,

> Use "SetStyleDefinitions"→False to preserve the original stylesheet:
> Note that some items will be missing style definitions (such as >delimiters, tables, etc.):

In summary, just evaluate

```wl
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

in the notebook.

I would like to make an important reminder to remove

````
```lang-wl
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
````

from the notebook before you click the "Submit to Repository" button. I almost submitted a function CombGraph without removing this.

When you done working, you can run

```wl
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Elegant"]
```

to go back to the elegant code environment.

Actually, there's some good news. The documentation tools and Submit to Repository button stay visible after doing

```wl
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Elegant"]
```

in a new ResourceFunction notebook.
[image]
I'm glad this issue was resolved.

Actually, it's not quite resolved. I think you have to save the notebook and click a button in the toolbar at the top like Deploy to the Cloud Publicly for this to work. Otherwise, it will just go to elegant code and the documentation toolbar will disappear.

This is also applicable to paclet files like .wl Wolfram Language files.
I have this.

[image]

I evaluate this

```wl
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

and I get this
[image]

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to keep the toolbar with the button Run Package and Go To while using the elegant code environment.

I was thinking whats a good button to press and I think Preview is a good one to press.

[image]

You can do Check, but if you don't want to check because you haven't added stuff yet, this isn't a good option. You can also deploy to the cloud for example, but if you're not ready again this is not a good option.

Here's a picture.
[image: preview]

I've also noticed that you can't insert a new cell for example with ExternalEvaluate for Python, R, SQL, or Julia. If you need to get to the Working environment, I think it's faster to just change the default in the Option Inspector than use SetOptions with InputNotebook.

Acutally you can still insert different cell types with elegant environment.
[image]